# BASH + COM port чтение в переменные, обработка

Tags: bash, com-порт

Бьюсь над проблемой. Концепция такова. Есть устройство на COM порте, по записи в него команды "g", посредством такой команды:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 & echo "g" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

устройство выдаёт серию из 4 значений такого вида:

```
0.00 0.00 23.40 23.69
```

Полный ввод и вывод из консоли такой:

```
dlex@workstation:/var/www/test/bash$ cat /dev/ttyUSB0 & echo "g" > /dev/ttyUSB0
[6] 18791
dlex@workstation:/var/www/test/bash$ 0.00 0.00 23.40 23.69
```

Всё бы хорошо, но это конечно только проверка адекватности вывода по запросу. Далее следует разобрать полученную строку на переменные, которые уйдут как значения в базу данных следующим образом:

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS=" " read LITRAGE FLOW T1 T2 ;

do 
[ -z "LITRAGE" ] && continue
mysql -u admin-um -pdrums um-jekeha << EOF
INSERT INTO main
(date, litrage, flow, thot, tcold)
VALUES
(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '$LITRAGE', '$FLOW', '$T1', '$T2')
EOF

done < ./log

exit 0
```

Здесь, до выполнения этого скрипта, я применил вывод cat в log файл, иначе ничего не выходило. Таким образом в базу он загоняет значения, с одним НО. В базу приходят 2 строки. в одной все значения 0, во второй актуальные значения, считанные ранее из устройства.
Вопрос первый, как реализовать чтение устройства сразу в переменную/переменные, без файла?
Вопрос второй, если я размещаю запрос "cat/echo" к устройству непосредственно в скрипте, ничего не происходит, как исправить? Хотелось бы исполнять это одним скриптом.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой скрипт:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | awk '{if($1!="") print "insert INTO main(date,litrage,flow,thot,tcold) \
VALUES(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),\
\x27"$1"\x27,\x27"$2"\x27,\x27"$3"\x27,\x27"$4"\x27);"}' | \
mysql -u admin-um -pdrums um-jekeha  &

echo "g" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Доработайте по необходимости. Основная идея: подаем весь вывод из COM порта на вход AWK, который по умолчанию разбивает строку по пробелам в переменные $1 $2 и т.п. В нем же проверяем `if($1!='')` что строка не пустая. И печатаем вашу строку `insert into` подставляя переменные. С экранированием кавычек я не разобрался и заменил их на `\x27` - код одинарной кавычки. Все что напечатал AWK подаем на вход mysql. Все это запускаем в фоне `&` и после этого подаем вашу команду 'g' на устройство. Во время отладки можете убрать последний `|` и mysql он на консоль напечатает готовый к выполнению sql-запрос.

Но остается вопрос как завершить потом cat, когда все будет сделано, он скорее всего так и продолжит висеть и ожидать ввод. В принципе если вы будете после этого раз в минуту подавать команду 'g' и устройство будет выдавать свои данные - возможно это то что вам и надо. Но очень на долго без работы висеть cat и соответственно mysql оставлять нельзя, потому как mysql может по таймауту потерять коннект к базе.

Comment: Спасибо. Не удалось его адекватно отработать. В таком виде не вносит в БД ничего, при некоторой модернизации вносит нули, видимо переменные не отрабатываются. Но идею понял, буду  думать в этом направлении.